# Laravel display a relationship data with soft delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to display the name of the user in the blade using Eloquent: Relationships. My code's can display data using relationship but if the data is soft deleted it gives me a error.

Here's my code.

// History Model//

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

// User model //

```
public function history()
{
    return $this->hasMany(History::class);
}
```

// Controller //

```
public function index()
{
    $histories = History::find(3);
    return view('booking.backend.content.history.index', compact('histories'));
}
```

// index.blade //

```
{{$history->user->name}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already fixed it.
In my model history I add withtrashed.

```
public function history()
{
    return $this->hasMany(History::class)->withTrashed();
}
```