# Attempt to read property "id" on null - show.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand at all why I have this mistake:
`Attempt to read property "id" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\admin\employees\show.blade.php)`

show.blade.php

```
'Category' => '<a href="'. route('admin.employee-categories.show', $model->category->id) . '">' . $model->category->name . '</a>',
```

Model Empolyee

```
    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EmployeeCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

I try:

```
'Category' => '<a href="'. route('admin.employee-categories.show', $model->category ? $model->category->id: '') . '">' . $model->category ? $model->category->name : ' ' . '</a>',
```

But then I have mistake - `Attempt to read property "name" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\admin\employees\show.blade.php)`

**UPD:**

In index.blade.php I SoftDelete one Employee.

Then I go to index.blade.php for EmployeeCertificates.

But then I should to see that Employee was deleted.

But I have `Attempt to read property "name" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\components\data-table.blade.php)`

**EmployeeCertificates index.blade.php:**

```
                       [
                            'attribute' => function($item) { return $item->employee->name; },
                            'label' => 'Сотрудник',
                            'style' => 'width: 30%; min-width: 200px;',
                            'filter' => [
                                'class' => \App\View\Components\Filters\Select::class,
                                'params' => [
                                    'name' => 'employee_id',
                                    'options' => $employees->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(),
                                    'value' => request()->get('employee_id', ''),
                                    'htmlAttributes' => '',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
```

**Employee model:**

```
    public function certificates(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmployeeCertificate::class, 'employee_id');
    }
```

Comment: 'Category' => '<a href="'. route('admin.employee-categories.show', $model->category ? $model->category->id: '') . '">' . ($model->category ? $model->category->name : ' ') . '</a>',

Comment: You have at least one employee with no category.  You can code defensively using the null coalesce operator `??`

Comment: @Snapey yes, may be

Comment: @ALL I added UPD

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
'Category' => '<a href="'. route('admin.employee-categories.show', $model->category?->id) . '">' . $model->category?->name . '</a>',
```

Comment: There has not been any mention of what PHP version is being used. The [nullsafe operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator) is only available from PHP 8

Comment: @Yinci PHP 8 is the only actively supported version of PHP at this time; https://www.php.net/supported-versions

Comment: That doesn't mean everyone has had the time to upgrade to 8 just yet

Comment: @Yinci It means an answer assuming PHP8 is entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have two arrows, you have to think defensively.  What if the relation is missing?

```
$item->employee->name;
```

What if `$item` does not have an employee? An error will be thrown since employee will be null, and you cannot get name from null

In many cases like this, using the null coalesce operator (> php 7.4) you can provide a fallback value if there is a null present in the referenced objects

```
$item->employee->name ?? 'no employee';
```

if `$item` does not have an employee relation then 'no employee' will be printed instead

Comment: Thanks! I use it now. But when I use it I have ```'no employee'``` for ```name``` I also have ```id``` for example. How can I delete EmployeeCertificate record of Employee if I soft delete one Employee. Because now I have record with  ```'no employee'``` and ```id```

Comment: As I understand it, in the links between an employee and a category of employees, you can add that you can select categories with soft removal, but then you need to check where this can appear (in API, for example)

But I don't understand how to do it

Comment: I mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039423/laravel-display-a-relationship-data-with-soft-delete But when I use ```trashWith``` It doesn't delete ```Employee``` for page ```EmployeeCertificates```

Comment: When you soft delete the employee, you need to think through the implications for other models.  I can't give you specifics because it depends on your application.  If an item belongs to an employee, and then you delete or soft delete the employee, what should happen?  Delete the item or set the employee_id null, or just leave it?  Its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Added function `boot` to `Employee` model. When you softDelete `Employee` your `EmployeeCertificates` softDelete too.

```
    public function certificates(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmployeeCertificate::class, 'employee_id');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($offer) {
            $offer->certificates()->delete();
        });
    }
```